# Qt@5.5 works, but not Qt

Tags: qt, homebrew, qmake

Attempting to run `qt` on my Mac, using the following homebrew commands:

- `brew install qt`
- `brew install qt-creator`

no errors occured. However, when I tried running `qt-creator`, I noticed I had to manually link `qmake`. When I attempted to run my program, I got the following error:

> :-1: error: failed to parse default search paths from compiler output

After attempting to add qt to the environment variables, it did not work.

What I finally resorted to was the following:

- `brew remove qt`
- `brew install qt@5.5`

Still, I had to manually link `qmake`, but this time it worked.

**Question**: Why does `qt@5.5` work, and not `qt`? Is there a fix/way to get `qt` to work?

Comment: Most likely a bad package. I suggest sticking to the official packages or building it from source yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue, with a brand new homebrew install of `qt` and `qt-creator`.

The short answer is make sure your selected "Kit" is using Clang. It can default to gcc and cause this error.

Longer answer:

1. Go to "Preferences → Build and Run → Qt Versions" and ensure you have a path to your qmake binary.

   - For my homebrew install, it was `/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.11.1/bin/qmake` (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in the open-file dialog).
2. Click OK, then re-navigate to "Preferences → Build and Run → Kits" and choose the `Desktop (default)` profile.

   - Choose a version in the "Qt version" dropdown.
   - Ensure that Clang is chosen for your compiler.

Comment: I had similar: wrong compiler specified - GCC, have to be - CLANG.